# Proportionality assumption test (SAS) for categorical predictors

Tags: categorical-data, survival, sas, cox-model

For Cox regression with all categorical predictors, I want to model time-dependent covariates (`time*cov` in `Proc PHREG`) to account for proportional hazard assumption violations. I am using the codes below with dummies for categorical predictors with >2 levels.

```
Proc phreg data=tem1s (where=(clinM ne '1')); 
  model time*event(0) = dps40 dps41 dps100 drcb drco dag55 dag65 dag75 dag85 
  dps40t dps41t dps100t dag55t dag65t dag75t dag85t /NODUMMYPRINT ties=Efron RL;  
  dps40t=dps40*time; dps41t=dps41*time; dps100t=dps100*time; 
  dgs44t=dgs44*time; dgs45t=dgs45*time; dgs53t=dgs53*time; dgs54t=dgs54*time;  
  hazardratio 'h11' dps40t; hazardratio 'h12' dps41t; hazardratio 'h13' dps100t;
  hazardratio 'h71' dag55t; hazardratio 'h72' dag65t; hazardratio 'h73' dag75t;   
  hazardratio 'h74' dag85t; 
  prop_test: test dag55t, dag65t, dag75t, dag85t;
run;
```

Here are issues:
I get normal / small parameter estimates for some of main effects but high estimates for interactions for all time-dependent covariates (e.g., `dag55=0.09` and `dag55t=-1174`). I get very absurdly high SE of dummies for main effects and interactions for time-dependent variables (e.g., SE of `dag55` and `dag55t` are `326.442` and `326442`, respectively SE of time-dependent variables are multiplied by `1000` for all). Some of the hazard ratios are suspect or are not computed. All terms in the model have 1 DF. Estimates for other variables look normal and chi-squared for the global test of proportional hazards is very small. Log looks normal with no errors.

When I use `log(time)` instead of time to create time-dependent variables, I get 0 DF for time interaction covariates. The log reads:

> ERROR: An illegal argument is used in the function call in statement number 1 at line 2566 column 1.

The statement was:

```
1  (2566:1)  dag55t = (dag55=0) * LOG( time=0 ).
```

The error goes away if I force `time>0` in the where statement (I have time>0 for all observations) but 0 DF and no estimates for time interactions. Interestingly, SE and parameters for main effect terms for time dependent variables are normal (e.g., `dag55 -0.02663` and `0.10444` (SE)) but a little different than when time is used while estimates for other covariates don't change. Also, in I use `time gt 0` in the `where` statement together with time for computing interaction, DF for interactions become 0 as with `log(time)`.

How I can include time-dependent interactions in the model?

Comment: Are you asking for help with the code?

Comment: Thanks @ gung!  Yes, I would appreciate any suggestions to help me model time interaction covariates.

Answer (score 1):

Log function can not have a 0 argument. You can do this way in SAS: if time=0 then time=time+1; or you assign "." to time variable that is 0.

Comment: thanks @ Deep North.  I solved the problem by correctly coding the time variable.